# create a window opencv

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

Happy new year.

I'm working on a project which I want to do now is to make a big black window and in order to put in the middle the capturing video. I have captured the video already with its window and now I want to create a new window but bigger than the first one and I want to put in the middle of this window the captured frame video.

Now my problem is that I'm getting the same size of the first window that I made which I want a window has bigger size than the captured frame, so let's suppose a captured a frame and around it a black space. My aim is to make a new one which is bigger and the background is black and in the middle the captured frame?

This is what I'm doing, here is the code

```
    cvNamedWindow("stabilized image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    IplImage* image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(900,650),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);

    cvZero( image );
    image=cvCloneImage(frame);

    cvShowImage("stabilized image", image );
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Changing the size doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is I'm getting the same size for both of the frames, I want a big frame which has a black background and in the middle of it the captured frame. but what I'm getting is just a frame without any background

Answer (score 2):

You should `cvCopy()` your captured frame *into* (the center of) your black frame.
Set a ROI of the same size as your source frame positioned in the center of your black frame, and `cvCopy()` into it.

Answer (score 1):

A window created with **cvNamedWindow** will have the size of the image when you set **CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**.

To resize it you have to do it with:

```
cvResizeWindow(const char* name, int width, int height)
```

So this should make it:

```
cvNamedWindow("stabilized image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
IplImage* image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(900,650),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);

cvZero( image );
image=cvCloneImage(frame);

cvShowImage("stabilized image", image );
cvResizeWindow("stabilized image", 1024, 768);
```

Check also:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html?highlight=cvnamedwindow#cvNamedWindow

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work out. I still get the same size of the window

Comment: Yes, I made I mistake in the order. After you show the image you should resize the windows, I already edited that. But this will also resize the image to the size of the window. If you want a black background I think you should create a new black image with the dimensions you want and add your previous image on top. The result image is the one you should display on the window.